# What am I doing wrong? - Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function - React GraphQL

Tags: reactjs, graphql

I read in other posts that to solve this issue I need to install "react": "16.8.0" and "react-dom": "16.8.0", I already did that and the error persists-

This is the first time messing with GraphQL, here is my code (simplified)

```
import React from 'react'
import { Query } from 'react-apollo'
import { gql } from 'graphql-tag'

const Header = () => (     
      <Query query={
         gql`
          {
            menu(id: "TWVudToy") {
              menuId            
            }
          }`
      }>

        { 
          ({ loading, error, data }) => {
            console.log(data)
            return <div>ff</div>
        }

        }
      </Query>

)

export default Header
```

The full error is

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    at Header (index.js:40)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:12740)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:14670)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:15194)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:18780)
    at workLoop (react-dom.development.js:18820)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:149)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:199)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:256)
    at replayUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:18052)
```

Comment: You've installed graphql-tag? as well as react-apollo?

Comment: try `import gql from 'graphql-tag'`

Comment: @Moriya yes I have, thank you

Comment: @thedude That worked, I can't tell you how thankful I am

Comment: @thedude can you put that as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @user3808307 sure :)

Comment: `import graphql from "babel-plugin-relay/macro";`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the default import from `graphql-tag`, e.g.:

```
import gql from 'graphql-tag'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using GraphQL it should be a directive so this:

```
<Query query={
   gql`
     {
       menu(id: "TWVudToy") {
...
```

Should be

```
<Query query={
  gql`
    query menu(id: 'TWVudToy') {
...
```

That, and really you should be abstracting out the query code. So something like this:

```
const MY_QUERY = gql`
  ...
```

Then it makes your query more readable:

```
<Query query={MY_QUERY} variables={...
```

Comment: thedude's comment above is what made the error go away. I will abstract out the query code, thank you

Comment: There's nothing syntactically wrong with the query as shown in the question. The query in this answer, however, is not syntactically correct. The correct syntax for a GraphQL document is outlined in the spec [here](http://spec.graphql.org/June2018/#sec-Language.Operations).